# xmppframework - enable log for send / receive

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I'm working on chat app using xmppframework in iOS. The framework contain sample demo that print send and receive log for xml. Now I implement same things in my app but no log is showing.

Example of log for sample app

```
2014-05-08 16:34:15:993 iPhoneXMPP[4839:1403] SEND: <?xml version='1.0'?>
2014-05-08 16:34:15:994 iPhoneXMPP[4839:1403] SEND: <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' to='meinantrieb.net'>
2014-05-08 16:34:16:384 iPhoneXMPP[4839:3503] RECV: <stream:stream xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" id="1364620848" from="meinantrieb.net" version="1.0" stream1:lang="en"/>
2014-05-08 16:34:16:384 iPhoneXMPP[4839:3503] RECV: <stream:features xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism><mechanism>ANONYMOUS</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms><c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" hash="sha-1" node="http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/" ver="GgBjinftMQ4H81m+4jSVXMg/dVU="/><register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register"/></stream:features>
```

Code For Adding Log in AppDelegate.m

```
#import "DDLog.h"
#import "DDTTYLogger.h"

// Log levels: off, error, warn, info, verbose
#if DEBUG
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
#else
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_INFO;
#endif
```

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Configure logging framework
    [DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];
}
```

Any help or suggestion will be well appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually performing any XMPP action that should be printed to the log? Your setup seems correct.

Comment: Yes.I have added CocoaLumberjack library using cocoapods

Comment: I mean connecting to the xmpp server, sending a message or something similar. Otherwise there is nothing to display in the logs

Comment: Yes. I want to print the xml string that are send/receive between server and client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this line to replace the code of configuring logging framework

```
[DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance] withLogLevel:XMPP_LOG_FLAG_SEND_RECV]
```

it is copied from the demo code of XMPPFramework

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 3.x, `DDLog` log levels are an enum, so it's not immediately possible to apply the XMPPFramework log levels.

One can enable *all* log messages:

```swift
DDLog.add(DDTTYLogger.sharedInstance, with: .all)
```

Comment: Does it mean XMPP_LOG_FLAG_SEND_RECV will be enable when you enable all log?

Comment: @FlorisM I guess so, and I see such log messages. However, I am not 100% sure how the hacky (?) extension XMPPFramework makes to DDTTYLogger translates into Swift.